# writing text beside an equation

Tags: equations, amsmath

I want to write text beside an equation to appear like the attatched photo. However, i'm keeping have an error message:

> ! Misplaced alignment tab character &. l.153 cj
>
> (\gamma_T;X,T)\delequal  &
>
> ```
>                                 \text{the number of firing times of reac.
> ```

can any one help ?? here is my code:
[image: attatched photo]

```
\begin{document} 
\usepackage{amsmath}   
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
cj (\gamma_T;X,T)\delequal  & \text{the number of firing times of reaction R_j} 
\text{ in the time interval [T,T_\gamma ] , given  X(x)=T }.\\
\end{align}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As is, your code is not compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is different from suggested one and not compilable. In particular, please observe that your big `T` is small `\tau` and `T_\gamma` is `\delta\tau`. Here is the code of the text from your picture, up to the equation number and your formulation of text part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   

\def\delequal{\stackrel{\triangle}{=}} % ?

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
%\begin{align}
\begin{gathered}
n_j (\delta\tau;\mathbf{x},\tau)\delequal   \text{the number of firing times of reaction}\\
 R_j\text{ in the time interval $[\tau,\tau+\delta\tau ]$, given  $\mathbf{X}(\tau)=\mathbf{x}$}.
\end{gathered}
%\end{align}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
cj (\gamma_T;X,T)\triangleq 
    &   \text{ the number of firing times of reaction $R_j$}   \\
    &   \text{ in the time interval $[T,T_\gamma ]$ , given  $X(x)=T$ }.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```